# How to use HtmlCompat?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

I have the following code:

`Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.privacy_policy_text)`

however, `Html.fromHtml()` is deprecated. I know  I am supposed to use `HtmlCompat` as indicated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat). However, I don't know what I have to include in my build.gradle file for that class to be available even after a lot of Googling.

I already have the following support libraries in my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current edition of the Android JavaDocs, there are notes about which artifact supplies a particular class.

[image: HtmlCompat JavaDocs]

Here, we see "belongs to Maven artifact androidx.core:core:1.0.0-beta1`. That tells you a specific artifact and version to use, though the version you may need to synchronize with other artifacts that you are using.

This is an `androidx` artifact, as a part of the grand refactoring of the Support Library. This may cause problems with your project, which is using the classic Support Library artifacts. You may wish to hold off on using `HtmlCompat` until you can switch your whole project over to `androidx` artifacts.

Comment: OK, but is there a way to add it to build.gradle and how? What is "artifact" please?

Comment: @Yar: `implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.0-beta1"`. But, as I note, moving to `androidx` is not easy. "Artifact" is the term used for a library or other thing that we add to a project via `implementation` or similar statements in the `dependencies` list in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks. Then, I guess, I'll try to use com.pixplicity.htmlcompat.HtmlCompat which is deprecated, but I guess if my app compiles with it, it will last, unless new versions of my app will be released later and the lib will be gone.

Comment: I'm not seeing that Maven line here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat.html

Comment: @Mark: They re-re-re-re-re-re-re-re-re-did the documentation. I created (and have not yet launched) https://androidx.tech to provide this sort of information. If you go through the "Packages" to find `androidx.core.text`, you will come to a list of all classes and their associated artifacts/versions, [such as this section for `HtmlCompat`](https://androidx.tech/packages/androidx.core.text/#htmlcompat). Clicking the name of an artifact [gives you details and a full version list](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/core/core/), and so on.